# cas delegated authenticaion: dynamic client id and secret in cas pac4j

Tags: cas, pac4j

I've [cas](/questions/tagged/cas) configuration as below

```
cas.authn.pac4j.typed-id-used=true
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].principal-attribute-id=preferred_username
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].secret=xxxxxxxxxx
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].client-name=salesforce
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].auth-url=https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].token-url=https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].profile-url=https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/userinfo
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].use-path-based-callback-url=false
cas.authn.pac4j.oauth2[0].profile-attrs.preferred_username=preferred_username
```

In the login page I need to get the user email-id and based on email id fetch the client id and secret from database and then use in redirect-url.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Please explain in details your login flow. In which login page are you referring to?CAS login page or oath server login page?

Comment: @leopal like cas welcome page -> show available clients like Salesforce, zoho or Standard login page in cas login welcome page. After user clicks salesforce -> ask user to enter email id. Based email id find the client id and secret. Basically want to pass id and secret dynamically. I'm checking cas webflow customization to change the standard login page to customized and don't know about pac4j customization.

Comment: When the user clicks on salesforce option, he is redirected to an external system right? He provides his email and then the response from salesforce returns to cas. Afterwards, cas redirects the authenticated user to the service that initialized the login process. So do you need to include additional attributes of the user to the initial service? If yes, then check [attribute release](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/integration/Attribute-Release.html).

Comment: @leopal actually no. If you see my above configuration I've not given id and secret. I've multiple id and secret which very from my client to client. If configure id and secret here the cas always redirect to salesfore with same id. But this id changes from client to client. I need a way to dynamically pass the id and secret

Comment: Which version of CAS are you using? CAS 5.3? CAS 6.1? other?

Comment: Also, you said that you want to separate different clients based on their input `emails`, is it possible to separate client based on the domain they visit? E.g. for service coming from `www.service1.com`, use saleforce config 1. For service coming from `www.service2.com`, use saleforce config 2......

Comment: @NgSekLong I'm using CAS 5.3. It's not possible to differentiate based on the service. We have multiple clients in he same service.

Comment: I think going to customize webflow is the best option I can come up with... from my own experience CAS natively doesn't provide what you ask for, see if other have better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get the user email-id and based on email id fetch the client id and secret from database and then use in redirect-url.

There is no way in CAS to modify the redirection-url for delegated authentication. The redirection-urls are built and calculated using pac4j automatically, and there is not a way out-of-the-box to dynamically manipulate that URL.

To accommodate this, you cannot rely on CAS creating pac4j clients for you automatically. Instead, you need to create your own pac4j clients manually. This means:

- You will need to design a Spring configuration class
- You will have to create and inject your own client into CAS
- You will need to modify your newly-built client with a special implementation of `RedirectionActionBuilder`. Every client object has access to a `RedirectionActionBuilder` that knows how to build redirect-urls. You will need to write your own to make changes to the redirect-url.

CAS will eventually execute this code to make the redirection happen:

```java
final View result;
final RedirectAction action = client.getRedirectAction(webContext);
if (RedirectAction.RedirectType.SUCCESS.equals(action.getType())) {
    result = new DynamicHtmlView(action.getContent());
} else {
    final URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(action.getLocation());
    final String url = builder.toString();
    LOGGER.debug("Redirecting client [{}] to [{}] based on identifier [{}]", client.getName(), url, ticket.getId());
    result = new RedirectView(url);
}
```

The key line is `client.getRedirectAction(webContext);`, which is where the redirect-action is used and if your client is using your own implementation of that concept, then that would be the one to determine the final URL.

**Alternatively**, you can modify the `DelegatedClientNavigationController.java` in your overlay and manipulate the url (and the above code) as you like.